# Extract keyword from line

Tags: shell, sed, awk, grep

I need to extract similar patterns from data below. The pattern starts with 
'.' or '*' then to the keyword I want, then followed by '*'. We can assume the format is

1. LSUFE-numbers_
2. PCRF-numbers_

Sample data

```
/home/mobaxterm/Data/FW/FW3/FW.3.1/releases/patch_PCRF-17717B1.jar,patch_PCRF-17717B1.jar,yschew,2015-10-21 11:31:58.000000000,patch
/home/mobaxterm/Data/FW/FW9/CW.1/releases/D/patch_FW_9.3.1.LSUFE-583B1_i86pc.jar,patch_FW_9.3.1.LSUFE-583B1_i86pc.jar,yschew,2015-10-21 11:31:58.000000000,patch,i86pc
```

Desired output

```
LSUFE-583B1
PCRF-17717B1
```

I have tried using answer from 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777901/extract-specific-words-from-a-line

```
sed -r 's/.*LSUFE-(\S+).*/\1/'
```

but it didn't work, all I got is a blank screen. Right now what I am thinking is doing something similar like this

```
sed -e 's/LSUFE-*/,/\_/' output.txt
```

but of course, I didn't get it to work, my idea is doing it 1 by 1 for each pattern, read from the matching pattern until it encounters an underscore.

Comment: Your output data does not exist in your input data (PCRF-17717B1)...

Comment: I updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
$ grep -oE '(LSUFE|PCRF)-[^._]*' input.txt  | uniq
PCRF-17717B1
LSUFE-583B1
```

The `uniq` is required because each line contains both the full path to the patch filename and the basename (i.e. without the path).

Alternatively, if the order of the output doesn't matter, you could use `sort -u` rather than `uniq` - this will also eliminate any duplicates that occur on multiple lines of the input.

Here's another alternative in perl:

```
perl -F, -a -e 'next unless $F[1] =~ s/.*((LSUFE|PCRF)-[^._]*).*/$1/  ; print $F[1],"\n"' input.txt
```

This performs the regexp search and replace only on field 2 (`$F[1]` in perl as perl arrays are zero-based), and then prints field 2.

This perl version appends the matching text as an extra field to the end of the input line:

```
perl -F, -a -e 'chomp ; next unless $F[1] =~ s/.*((LSUFE|PCRF)-[^._]*).*/$1/ ; print $_,",",$F[1],"\n"' input.txt
```

It uses `chomp()` to strip the trailing `\n` from the input line, then prints the input line (`$_`), a comma, the modified field 2, and a newline.

Comment: It worked, thanks! I see what I am missing now. Thanks again.
What if I want to append the word to the end of the line where it matches?

Comment: Based on your edit, is there no way to do this using grep?

Comment: the perl version wasn't a response to your extra question, it was just another way of performing the original task, i hadn't even seen your comment when i wrote it.   BTW i have no idea what you mean by "What if I want to append the word to the end of the line where it matches?"   Whatever that means, I doubt if `grep` can do it because `grep` is only good for finding patterns, not for appending stuff to lines.  With the perl version, you can append whatever you like to the line just by adding it to the print statement.

Comment: Oh, what I meant was take the output of grep `PCRF-17717B1` and append it to the end of the line where the pattern matches, like the output below

`/home/mobaxterm/Data/FW/FW3/FW.3.1/releases/patch_PCRF-17717B1.jar,patch_PCRF-17717B1.jar,yschew,2015-10-21 11:31:58.000000000,patch,PCRF-17717B1`

Comment: @xeon, answer updated with append version of perl one-liner

Comment: Hmm I noticed something, I was playing around with the solution to understand it better, I changed the PCRF or LSUFE to some other words such as Test or installer, it then append  the entire word (Test . jar or installer.jar ) to the end of the line

`/home/mobaxterm/Data/FW/FW9/releases/D/patch_FW_9.3.1.Testing_i86pc.jar,patch_FW_9.3.1.Testing_i86pc.jar,yschew,2015-10-21 11:31:58.000000000,patch,i86pc,patch_FW_9.3.1.Testing_i86pc.jar`

Comment: unless you actually post what you changed in the regexp, i have no way of even beginning to guess what happened.  in any case, let's move this to chat.  http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/unix-and-linux

Answer (score 0):

Only the catched info

```
sed  's/.*\(LSUFE-\([^_.]*\)[_.].*/\1/' YourFile
```

catched added to the end with `,` as separator

```
sed  's/.*\(LSUFE-\([^_.]*\)[_.].*/&,\1/' YourFile
```

With several pattern at once

```
sed  -e 's/.*\(LSUFE-\([^_.]*\)[_.].*/\1/' -e 's/.*\(PCRF-\([^_.]*\)[_.].*/\1/' YourFile
```

*with GNU sed*

```
sed 's/.*\(\(LSUFE\|PCRD\)-\([^_.]*\)[_.].*/\1/'
```